# Почему то не читается медиа запрос в <style>

Tags: html, css, style

Вынес медиа запрос в `html` с помощью тега `style`, все стили читаются, а медиа запрос нет.

Элемент кода

```
<style media scoped>
        @media(min-width:320px) and (max-width: 768px) {
          h1 {
            font-size: 18px;
            text-align: center;
          }
          .header {
            padding: 30px 0 10px 0; 
          }
          .header p {
            margin-top: 30px;
            text-align: center;
          }
        }
      .header{
        padding: 50px 0 130px 0;
        text-align: left;
        background-image: url(/img/header-bg.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        color: white;
      }
      .header p {
        margin-top: 90px;
      }
</style>
```

Ссылка на страницу - http://ecoexspert.kz/

Comment: тэг `style` надо в `head` подключать, а не в `body`

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, забыл про это правило, хотя при внимательном рассмотрении, понял что стили и в body читаются, просто их перебивают стили с бутстрапа ((

Answer (score 0):

В общем, стили читаются и в body, просто перебиваются более специфичными стилями из внешнего стилевого файла.